# Does iOS universal link can forward to App at first time user install app?

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I want to make my app automatic get ref code from Universal link at the first time install app from Appstore and click Open from AppStore.
Can I do it in this case ?

Here is my use case:

- I'm using Firebase Dynamic Link to make short link:
- Setup Deep Link: [https://sample.com/refcode="ABC"](https://sample.com/refcode=%22ABC%22)
- Open the deep link in iOS App: --> choose my app ( bundle id & Appstore ID )
- --> Output Dynamic Link: https://sample.page.link/abc

I want to make user who using Mobile and open this link:

- User open app in the AppStore ( OK )
- User Click "Install" and "Open" app from Appstore ( OK )
- Expected Appstore open App and pass Deep Link [https://sample.com/refcode="ABC"](https://sample.com/refcode=%22ABC%22) to the app at the first time open App. Then I can get parameter "refcode" from link to automatic fill to a Textfield in my app.

Can we do this action with Apple Store ?

Thank you